# How to extract the information based on a column from a dataframe into a new data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe "data" like following:

```
data

  Names   value1   value2  value3
  TNHJ    -3.22    -0.11   1.88
  JKIN    -6.90    -4.23   0.98
  EFGT     7.56    -8.90   9.34
```

From this data frame "data" based on the column "value1" I want to extract only negative information into a new dataframe.

```
Result:

  Names   value1   value2  value3
  TNHJ    -3.22    -0.11   1.88
  JKIN    -6.90    -4.23   0.98
```

I tried like following but it didn't work.

```
within(data, value1[value1<0])
```

Comment: Try `result <- subset(data, value1 < 0)`

Comment: `data[data$value1 <0,]`

Answer (score 2):

dplyr library `filter` is your helper:

```html
library(dplyr)
new_df <- data %>% filter(value1 <0)
```